# HTML canvas element creating undesired white border

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

There's probably a real simple explanation for this, but I'm struggling really hard to find it. I'm trying to implement a crop picture feature and I'm getting an undesired border on the right and bottom sides of the picture, as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLQSI.jpg. I think I've narrowed it down to something having to do with the first image translation that happens when I crop the picture. Here's the applicable code (the doubling of the cropped image size in `submitPhotoUpload` is due to some unknown halving of the picture height in my code. Advice for that would be welcome too):

```
cropPhoto: function(evt){

    var formType = App.UploadPhotoView.whichForm;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("crop-canvas-preview-"+formType);
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    if(this.canvasHidden){
        canvas.style.display = 'inline';
        App.UploadPhotoView.canvasHidden = false;
    }

    var x1 = App.UploadPhotoView.x1;
    var y1 = App.UploadPhotoView.y1;
    var width = App.UploadPhotoView.width;

    var previewSize = $("#upload-div-"+formType).height() * 0.25;
    var resizeX = App.UploadPhotoView.scalingFactorX;
    var resizeY = App.UploadPhotoView.scalingFactorY;
    var img = document.getElementById("preview-photo-"+formType);

    context.clearRect(0, 0, previewSize, previewSize);
    context.drawImage(img, x1*resizeX, y1*resizeY, width*resizeX,
                      width*resizeY, 0, 0, previewSize*2, previewSize);
},

submitPhotoUpload: function(){
    var formType = "pic";
    if ($('#preview-photo-'+formType).attr('src') != '#') {
        var uploadImage = new Image();
        uploadImage.src = document.getElementById('crop-canvas-preview-'+formType).toDataURL();

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = uploadImage.width * 3;
        canvas.height = uploadImage.height * 6;

        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(uploadImage, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var newPhoto = App.Photo.createRecord({
            filename: canvas.toDataURL(),
            location: this.get('location'),
            description: this.get('description')
        });
        this.get('store').commit();
        resetPhotoUpload(formType);
    }else{
        this.set('submissionFailed', true);
    }
},
```

Comment: I'm working one up right now, might take me a little while because of all the emberjs stuff and what not

Comment: you don't need ember to show your cropPhoto function in action on its own. First course of action would be to do a `console.log(img, x1*resizeX, y1*resizeY, width*resizeX, width*resizeY, 0, 0, previewSize*2, previewSize)` and see if those values are what you expected them to be based on what cropPhoto should do.

Comment: The thing is that the preview of my cropped photo looks perfect, it's only when I translate that photo to another canvas and then to a dataURL that it get's messed up. The console.log seemed to show all the values were correct leading me to believe that the toDataURL is somehow taking more of the canvas than I want it to

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are using fractional values with the clearing and clipping.

The `clearRect` call will clear on sub-pixel basis which means it can leave "half" pixel clipped.

The clip however cannot clip the image with sub-pixels as images are pixel based and will truncate the value to match an integer value, hence you get a small gap in the final result.

Luckily this is easy to get around by simply forcing the values to integer values:

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/mcLNs/)**

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, previewSize|0, previewSize|0);
context.drawImage(img, (x1*resizeX)|0, (y1*resizeY)|0, (width*resizeX)|0,
                  (width*resizeY)|0, 0, 0, previewSize|0, previewSize|0);
```

Of course, you might consider doing this outside the function call. If you need a more accurate rounding just add `0.5` to the values before doing as here, shifting 0 bits (which force a float number to integer) or use `Math.round()` instead.

Here is the result:

[image: Result]

<sup>left: cleared and clipped using frational positions, right: using integer values</sup>

Comment: This solves the issue of the blurred lines along the edges, but doesn't address my main concern which is the ~50px border (shows up as the background color of whatever the container is) around the right and bottom sides. Check the imgur link I posted above to see exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: @midma101 ah.... that wasn't too obvious as the image at imgur is blending quite well with the  background and I frankly never noticed. The only border I saw was the white one :-) If you could provide a fiddle that would be helpful so we can see what values are at play.

Comment: No worries, I was able to figure it out myself after some tinkering, it had to do with the image being drawn on only 85% of the canvas initially. Thanks for the help on the blurred edges though!